# How can I pull a Cookie's value into a css id statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using [cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) as a means to hold onto info entered into a form's hidden field. There are four different options, and upon each option's being clicked, I want to give the browser a cookie with a value relevant to that option.

These options are hidden by default, but if the user subsequently navigates back after having chosen a value, I want to check for their cookie, then read that cookie's value, take that value as a var, then display the appropriate option as determined from the read cookie.

something like:

if the cookie is set

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'option_number1')
```

then when someone navigates to the page:

```
var check_cookie = $.cookie('cookie_name');

    if(check_cookie){
var option_number = $('cookie_name').val();
$(option_number).css("display","block");
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $.cookie(cookie_name) returned a value in quotes (and returned the value to begin with) those had to be stripped out then the # sign needed to be appended to the front for Id use, after which it could be treated as whatever:

```
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('cookie_name');
    check_cookie= check_cookie.replace("\"", "");

           alert(check_cookie);
$("#"+check_cookie).css("display","inline-block")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#' + option_number).css("display","block");
```

Or simply

```
$('#' + option_number).show()
```

Actually you have to prepend a `#` while using an `ID selector`. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is the documentation for the `ID selector`.

Comment: does the whole of the id selector not need to be in quotes?

Comment: @Abernasty Id selector should be a string. option_number was already a string. We are just appending a character `#` to the string. Clear.? :)

Comment: right, I'm down with the need to append the #, but two things: 1) the value returned by $.cookie is "option_number1" 2) in the documentation you linked to and in my experience, Id strings are indicated to be such by being incapsulated in "'s, e.g. $("#idString"). So from the value I'm getting from the cookie.js, and your suggestion, what I'm ending up with is something like $(#"option_number1")

Comment: @Abernasty No. :) It will be evaluated as `$("#option_number1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$("#"+option_number).show();
```

Comment: is it not redundant to append the '#' twice?